# Access Union with NULL columns not working

Tags: ms-access

I have two select queries I am trying to perform UNION on with NULL as columns. Its working fine for one select query but not for other. Please help

I am calculating SUM of ID 1234 for B&C type and grouping them in final select query on ID and performing union on sum of same ID for FTN type.

This means B&C select query will always have "Case" value and **not G.** And FTN will have G value and **not Case**.

Problem with the union query is, its generating correct result for B&C
C but showing NULL for G in FTN select query. How do I fix it?

Here is my query

```
select [ID],sum([case2018])  as [Case18] , NULL AS [G18]  from 
    (SELECT [ID], [ID Was], SUM([Cases]) AS [Case2018], NULL AS [G2018] FROM TblX
    WHERE [Package Type]='B&C' and [Year]=2018 and  [ID]= 1234 
    GROUP BY [ID], [ID Was]) 
GROUP BY [ID]

union

select [ID], NULL AS [Case18] , sum([G2018]) as [G18]  from 
    (SELECT [ID], [ID Was], SUM([G]) AS G18 ,NULL as [Case2018] FROM TblX
    WHERE [Package Type]='FTN' and [Year]=2018 and [ID]= 1234 
    GROUP BY [ID], [ID Was]) 
GROUP BY [ID]
```

Comment: in a nutshell (and basically what others have kinda, sorta stated) ... for the second half of the union ... outer query is looking for column named `G2018` ... but the inner query has named the column `G18`; try using the same column name for the inner and outer tables; though I'd probably consider Wolfgang's (simpler) queries.

Answer (score 1):

The second query can't work, because the inner query does not select a field named `[G2018]`.

I think that this nesting of queries isn't necessary. I guess that you wanted the following:

```
SELECT [ID], SUM([Cases]) AS [Case18], NULL AS [G18] 
FROM TblX 
WHERE [Package Type]='B&C' AND [Year]=2018 AND [ID]=1234 
GROUP BY [ID]
UNION
SELECT [ID], NULL AS [Case18] , SUM([G]) AS [G18]
FROM TblX 
WHERE [Package Type]='FTN' AND [Year]=2018 AND [ID]=1234 
GROUP BY [ID]
```

Well, and having a little closer look, doesn't the following single `SELECT` produce the desired result?

```
SELECT [ID], [Package Type], SUM([Cases]) AS [Case18], SUM([G]) AS [G18]
FROM TblX 
WHERE [Package Type] In ('B&C', 'FTN') AND [Year]=2018 AND [ID]=1234 
GROUP BY [ID], [Package Type]
```

Answer (score 0):

A site I use is http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm  Free online sql formatting tool, beautify sql code instantly for SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, MySQL, Sybase and Access.  This gives me readable SQL.

For analysis I then in excel pasted B&C side-by-side with FTN and spotted the error. Then I rearranged a few items in the FTN and changed the spelling to G2018 for

```
               NULL     AS [Case2018],
               Sum([g]) AS [G2018]

SELECT [id],
       Sum([case2018]) AS [Case18],
       NULL            AS [G18]
FROM   (SELECT [id],
               [id was],
               Sum([cases]) AS [Case2018],
               NULL         AS [G2018]
        FROM   tblx
        WHERE  [package type] = 'B&C'
               AND [year] = 2018
               AND [id] = 1234
        GROUP  BY [id],
                  [id was])
GROUP  BY [id]
UNION
SELECT [id],
       NULL         AS [Case18],
       Sum([g2018]) AS [G18]
FROM   (SELECT [id],
               [id was],
               NULL     AS [Case2018],
               Sum([g]) AS [G2018]
        FROM   tblx
        WHERE  [package type] = 'FTN'
               AND [year] = 2018
               AND [id] = 1234
        GROUP  BY [id],
                  [id was])
GROUP  BY [id]
```